# How to fix this old frame glitch appearing when animating view?

Tags: ios, swift, animation, uiview, uiviewanimation

I have a Header view that contains pager view (FSPagerView), which has an item (FSPagerViewCell) that contains bar chart, 2019, *year review* texts. I'm trying to scale down Header at certain times with such code:

```
private func setSelfHeightAnimated(height: CGFloat)
{
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, animations: {
        self.selfHeightAnchor.constant = height
        self.superview?.layoutIfNeeded()
    })
}

private func setPagerHeightAnimated(height: CGFloat)
{
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, animations: {
        self.pagerHeightAnchor.constant = height
        self.layoutIfNeeded()
//            self.pagerView.layoutIfNeeded()
//            self.pagerView.layoutSubviews()
//            self.pagerView.cellForItem(at: 0)?.layoutIfNeeded()
//            self.pagerView.cellForItem(at: 0)?.setNeedsDisplay()
//            self.superview?.layoutIfNeeded()
//            self.setNeedsDisplay()
//            self.pagerView.setNeedsDisplay()
    })
}
```

However, the old frame glitch is very visible. What could be missing? Here is the video: https://streamable.com/owsdi

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have an 1st layout and a 2nd layout, and an animation that leads from the 1st to the 2nd.
Currently, the 1st layout is faded out and the 2nd layout is faded in during the animation, which gives you the „glitch“.
I assume what you want to achieve is:
- The top part (History, 2019, Year review) should keep their height, and
- only the columns below should shrink/expand, while the lower table slides up or down.
A solution probably is that you animate only the height of a subview that contains the 2 columns.
If the header view is set to adopt its height to its contents, then I expect that the required effect is shown without a glitch.

EDIT:

If you definitively had to animate the upper part as a whole, one possibility may be (that I consider as ugly) to set the alpha value of History, 2019, and Year to 0 immediately before the animation begins. Then these texts would only fade in so the glitch with double images at different places would be avoided.

Comment: 2019, year review texts and columns are inside an FSPagerView. I must resize the FSPagerView, otherwise it will be a nasty mess. What's the other way?

Comment: what's the solution to rerender the whole FSPagerView during each frame of animation? So that I would not need any of this hack bs

Comment: I don’t have any experience with `FSPagerView`. But is seems to me that you expect that one part of the view (the upper 3 texts) remain unscaled, and only the lower part (the columns) scale during the animation. If so, I think you have to specify this behaviour somewhere, e.g. with different constraints, as I suggested in my answer.

Comment: your answer is not universal enough. Even if you are not familiar with FSPagerView, how could I set a simple UIView to rerender itself on each frame of animation?

Comment: Then I hope somebody has a better idea. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Try like this to avoid glitching.

```
private func setSelfHeightAnimated(height: CGFloat)
{
    self.selfHeightAnchor.constant = height

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, animations: {
        self.layoutIfNeeded()
        self.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    })
}

private func setPagerHeightAnimated(height: CGFloat)
{
    self.pagerHeightAnchor.constant = height

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, animations: {
        self.layoutIfNeeded()
        self.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    })
}
```

Comment: This is like syntax only. To avoid glitching keep your constraint changes in before and after animation.